# Rails 3.1 - Scope for multiple objects through belongs_to association?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, scope, belongs-to

```rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :items
end
```

I'd like to do the following:

```rb
@items = @account.items.where(...)
@categories = @items.categories.order(...)
```

`@items.categories` should get all categories of `@items` through the `belongs_to` association. The best I've come up with is:

```rb
@categories = @items.map{|item| item.category }
```

But isn't there a scope for managing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the categories from an account by going through the items, I think you could do something like

`has_many :categories, :through => :items`

in your `Account` model, and then just call `account.categories`

Also, for the record, the `map` you're doing there does n+1 queries (it should be something like `@categories = @items.includes(:category).map{...}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your suggestion will work, but I'd like to change the @items dynamically in my controller (filter, search) and want to display them in the associated categories. Sorry, that I didn't make this clear enough in my question. But you're definitely right with the map command, there I should use includes.